# Feature request: Bounty available in signature

Tags: feature-request, bounties, signatures

For all bounty hunters (or simply because you want to answer hard questions) if a user has an opened bounty, it could show in the signature, p.e.:

Bounty opened (in any of his questions):

```
Username
56 *8
Bounty opened!
```

If there's no bounty on any of the user's questions, the signature will show as usual:

```
Username
56 *8
```

This way you will notice the user needs some help.

Comment: -1 for reasons described in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounty-hunters can already go and find questions that have a bounty by clicking on the featured questions tab -- surely that's even easier than randomly happening across someone's signature.

This seems like extraneous information that doesn't add meaningful value.  That is, bounty hunters aren't likely to care about the user they're hunting for -- and if they are they can see that information attached to the question on the featured tab.  So adding this information to the signature just takes up some more space.

Besides the point, indicating a user has opened a bounty still doesn't reveal the question they've opened the bounty on, so any viewer is still a click away.

On the flip side, I can't imagine any benefit to a user advertising they've opened a bounty, opening a bounty already advertises their question in a reasonable way.

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. Explained that way it seems nonsense to add that info to a signature.

Comment: @Oscar, actually you could make the 'Bounty opened!' text a link to the question.

Comment: @Lance, I'd contend that's still an unnecessary addition, why is having the question appear on the "featured" tab not enough?

Comment: @Mark, I don't really see the usefulness myself, except for myself, since I lose track of whether I have feature requests out now, since they're not on my questions.

Comment: @Lance, the problem is, what if the user has more than one bounty opened? The link can only go to one question, which one will you choose?

Comment: @Oscar, I didn't think you could do more than one bounty at a time.

Comment: @Lance, you're right, I didn't read the bounties faq, only one bounty is allowed by user

Answer (score 0):

There's no real benefit to coupling bounties with specific users. If you want to help a specific user, you shouldn't need a bounty to motivate you. If you want to get bounties, why are you restricting yourself to hunting by user instead of looking at the Featured tab? No matter how you look at it, people seeking to address one or the other don't need the opposite element.

Addressing both (helping a specific person *and* winning the bounty) is accomplished as basically a side-effect of addressing one or the other. Making both your goal limits your contributions by reducing the pool of questions you want to look at. Which means less people helped, and less bounties earned. So while it wouldn't harm the system directly, the people who would use such information stand to gain far less on both fronts.

Comment: Yeah, as I said to Mark, it's nonsense to add that info. I didn't think it through.